# How to fix the combo box that close automatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox

I have combo box in my win form. when i click on it in first time. it close automatically and after that i can open it and choose an item!
it is unexpected for me!!

this is my code in its event:

```
 Private Sub cmbType_Enter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbType.Enter
        cmbType.DroppedDown = True
 End Sub


 Private Sub cmbType_Leave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbType.Leave
        cmbType.DroppedDown = False
        cmbType.BackColor = Color.White
 End Sub
```

can any one to help me please?

Comment: Do you need to select multiple options from combobox?

Comment: and also provide more information like what you have tried?

Comment: have you any logic on combo box click event?

Comment: no. i want to just select an item. in the first time when click on it, it close immediately and i can't see anything. but in the other time it no any any problem

Comment: Try this code by putting on SelectedIndexChanged event:
if(!comboBox1.DroppedDown) 
   comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code by putting on SelectedIndexChanged event:  **if(!comboBox1.DroppedDown)  comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;**